requestReview() causes screen freeze before displaying review prompt
I'm using @Environment(\.requestReview) in my app to request reviews. However, when requestReview() is called, the screen freezes before the review prompt appears. Animations continue to play as expected, but I lose the ability to interact with the UI (e.g., tapping buttons, scrolling lists, etc.) during this period. Here's the relevant code:
@Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        // View content
    }
    .onChange(of: rstatus) { newValue in

        switch newValue {
        case .ready:
            Task { @MainActor in
                requestReview()
            }

        // Other cases omitted for brevity

        }
    }
}

How can I prevent this screen freeze and ensure a smoother transition when requesting a review?

What operating system are you experiencing this on? Why do you have it wrapped in a Task? Is this on-device or in a simulator? Does it happen in both DEBUG and RELEASE builds?

@jnpdx iOS, the code is from Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

DEBUG, I am unable to create a RELEASE build.

Why can’t you make a release build?

Apologies, I meant this issue occurs in both DEBUG and RELEASE builds. @jnpdx
